What does "snubbed out" mean?
I am confused by the meaning of the term "snubbed out." I will list some examples that I came across.

I applied for the position of supervisor, but was quickly snubbed out when the HR manager told me that they only want to hire a local for supervisory/management positions.
That idea was snubbed out real quick by Buster when I gave the uniformed officers, who were also in on the joke, the list of people I wanted picked up.
Even though her portrayal of the unapologetic Jones is legendary, Cattrall was snubbed out of an Emmy win each time.
Another defenseman who was snubbed out of his award was Paul Coffey.

Examples 1 and 2 seem to mean "was rejected," "was dismissed," or "was disappointed," but I am not sure.
Examples 3 and 4 seem to mean "did not win something when they should have," but I am not sure either.
As I said, I am confused by the usage of "snubbed out" in these examples. Can someone explain?

They were overlooked, and were left feeling snubbed.

It's an emerging usage, almost certainly gaining most of its traction from stub out (a cigarette or cigar), but probably in the minds of some speakers/writers, #3 and #4 carry semantic overtones of "unjustly dismissed, ignored, passed over,..." from the established sense of snub as well as stub out = squash, put out, eliminate,... But see John Lawler's comments under my answer to the linked question, pointing out that there are "phonosemantic reasons" for such usages.

...both the sense and "traction" are probably also influenced by alliteration from rub out, grub out, scrub out,...

In 3 and 4, she/he was snubbed, and the out-of phrase tells you what they didn't receive. It seems a pretty standard usage (cf "conned out of X", "tricked out of X", "voted out of X" - look up out). I don't know what other preposition you'd use there. The others are more like a phrasal verb. Wiktionary gives "stub out" as a meaning of snub. Not everything with the same words is the same construction.

In the first two examples, rejected works if substituted and deprived can  be substituted in 3 & 4

@FumbleFingers Still more answers misplaced into comments! This is the third time I'll've reminded you about this today; there shan’t be a fourth.

@tchrist: It's a duplicate! I answered this years ago, and it's hardly worth creating a new answer just because there's been a slight extension of the meaning from "put out, extinguished" to "eliminated, rejected".
